# MERN Passport Deserialize Called Twice on Every Request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, mern

I'm using mern.io for my app along with Passport and express-sessions. For every request, deserializeUser is being called twice for the same request. It's not an issue with express.static or express.favicon as other users have pointed out as possible culprits. The first time it's being called req.user is undefined. The second time it gets called, req.user is correct. The userObject in deserializeUser is correct in both cases:

```
{ userId: '1234',
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  email: 'asdf@aol.com' }
```

Here is my server.js:

```
import Express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);

// Webpack Requirements
import webpack from 'webpack';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';

// Initialize the Express App
const app = new Express();

// Set Development modes checks
const isDevMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || false;
const isProdMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || false;

// Run Webpack dev server in development mode
if (isDevMode) {
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: 
config.output.publicPath }));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}

// React And Redux Setup
import { configureStore } from '../client/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import routes from '../client/routes';
import { fetchComponentData } from './util/fetchData';
import serverConfig from './config';
import serverRoutes from './routes/routes';

app.use(compression());
app.use(Express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/client')));
app.use(cookieParser('somethingsomething'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: false }));

require('./passportConfig')(passport);
app.use(expressSession({
  name: 'testApp',
  secret: 'somethingsomething',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ url: process.env.DBURL }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 36000 * 24 * 14,
    secure: false,
  },
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});

app.use('/api', serverRoutes);


// Render Initial HTML
const renderFullPage = (html, initialState) => {
  const head = Helmet.rewind();

// Import Manifests
const assetsManifest = process.env.webpackAssets && JSON.parse(process.env.webpackAssets);
const chunkManifest = process.env.webpackChunkAssets && JSON.parse(process.env.webpackChunkAssets);

  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        ${head.base.toString()}
        ${head.title.toString()}
        ${head.meta.toString()}
        ${head.link.toString()}
        ${head.script.toString()}

        ${isProdMode ? `<link rel='stylesheet' href='${assetsManifest['/app.css']}' />` : ''}
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://res.cloudinary.com/hashnode/image/upload/v1455629445/static_imgs/mern/mern-favicon-circle-fill.png" type="image/png" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"><div>${html}</div></div>
        <script>
          window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)};
          ${isProdMode ?
          `//<![CDATA[
          window.webpackManifest = ${JSON.stringify(chunkManifest)};
          //]]>` : ''}
        </script>
        <script src='${isProdMode ? assetsManifest['/vendor.js'] : '/vendor.js'}'></script>
        <script src='${isProdMode ? assetsManifest['/app.js'] : '/app.js'}'></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};

const renderError = err => {
  const softTab = '&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;';
  const errTrace = isProdMode ?
    `:<br><br><pre style="color:red">${softTab}${err.stack.replace(/\n/g, `<br>${softTab}`)}</pre>` : '';
  return renderFullPage(`Server Error${errTrace}`, {});
};

// Server Side Rendering based on routes matched by React-router.
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).end(renderError(err));
    }

    if (redirectLocation) {
      return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    }

    if (!renderProps) {
      return next();
    }

    const store = configureStore();

    return fetchComponentData(store, renderProps.components, renderProps.params)
      .then(() => {
        const initialView = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </Provider>
        );
        const finalState = store.getState();

        res
          .set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
          .status(200)
          .end(renderFullPage(initialView, finalState));
      })
      .catch((error) => next(error));
  });
});

// start app
app.listen(serverConfig.port, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(`MERN is running on port: ${serverConfig.port}! Build something amazing!`); // eslint-disable-line
  }
});

export default app;
```

Here is my passportConfig.js:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const request = require('request');
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL;
const token = process.env.TOKEN;
const User = require('./models/user');
import Config from './config';

const API_URL = (typeof window === 'undefined' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') ?
  process.env.BASE_URL || (`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || Config.port}/api`) : '/api';

module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.serializeUser((userObject, done) => {
    done(null, userObject);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((userObject, done) => {
    if (userObject.adminUser) done(null, userObject.adminUser);
    else done(null, userObject);
  });

  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true, // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
  }, (req, email, password, done) => {
  const proj = {
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1,
    email: 1,
  };
  User.findOneAsync({ email }, proj)
  .then(user => {
    const userData = {
      userId: user._id,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
    };
    return done(null, userData);
  });
})
);

passport.use('signUp', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true,
}, (req, email, password, done) => {
  request({
    url: `${API_URL}/signIn`,
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
      email,
      password,
    },
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    headers: {
    Authorization: token,
    },
  }, (err, resp, body) => {
    const respBody = body || {};
    if (err) return done(err);

    if (!respBody.email) return done(null, false, { message: respBody.err });

    return done(null, { user: respBody });
  });
}));
};
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?